# OpenCMS - Best approach for showing rotating references

Tags: java, opencms

I would like to add on the right column of my site a rotating references section. Each reference would have some text + name of person + company name. It does not need to be structured (open text is also ok).

I would then want opencms to rotate between 20 difference references each time a page is displayed. I can keep a session scope counter holding which reference we last showed.

I need a way to manage the references (users not programmers) over time.

My question is which would be the best way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use structured content for the references (`reference.xsd`) and use the `contentload-tag` to loop through it. 
Then use any jquery script to to the rotation display, there are many scripts out there. Or maybe something like http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/featuredcontentglider.htm

If you make the references structured, it will be easier for the end user to edit the references, while not messing up the layout.